# How to add a relative date filter in Outsystems?

Tags: filter, dashboard, outsystems, relative-date

I've built a dashboard with many widgets using Outsystems. I've set up a date input parameter where the user can filter all the data by start date and by end date.
This all works great, but now I want to add an option to filter using relative dates. What I mean is, I want the user to be able to choose between a closed list of option (Last Month, This Month, This Quarter, This Year etc). Once they choose a relative date, it would override the date input parameter.

I'm having trouble finding any material for filtering relative dates, specifically in Outsystems.

All help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the start date based on the filter using the build in DateTime functions.

Last Month:

```
StartDate = AddMonths(CurrDate(),-1)
```

Last Quarter

```
StartDate = AddMonths(CurrDate(),-3)
```

Last year:

```
StartDate = AddYears(CurrDate(),-1)
```